# Not working "prepend" html5 image upload preview (dom)

Tags: jquery, html, dom, upload, preview

I have problem, when i dynamic add field for upload with jquery:

```
$('.content div').prepend(
    '<div'
        + '<input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple>'
        + '<div id="messages"></div>'
    + '</div>'
);
```

div #messages shows images preview and input upload images, before upload i can show images on #messages box.

when i add this:

```
<input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple>
<div id="messages"></div>
```

in html, all works, but by jquery not works :(
i use this html5 show before upload script: http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/filedrag/2/index.html
http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/filedrag/2/filedrag.js

how to edit this plugin to work with dom ?

Comment: You need to add the `addEventListener` calls to your newly created elements, or use a delegated event.

Comment: where is your file upload concept? we need code for that

Comment: i do not upload images now, i want create images preview ;)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how i can add this? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: The primary issue was that the filedrag.js script was getting loaded before the file input fields were prepared in the DOM. Once the script was loaded asynchronously, the subsequent calls worked.

Try this:

```
$("#fileselect").change(function() {
  var imgStr = "<img src='"+$(this).val()+"'/>";
  $("#messages").html(imgStr);
});
```

Comment: where i can use this? this plugin use plain js

Comment: Call this function just after your `prepend()` statement ends.

Comment: not work, on console return:

    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/fakepath/wallpaper.jpg

Comment: if you notice the error, it interprets the filename as `C:/fakepath/wallpaper.jpg`. Within the function can you try doing `imgStr = imgStr.replace('/fakepath','');`

Comment: nope, /fakepath this is my path, jquery automatic generate this message, becouse this method not allow open images. I must debug this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Where have you added the function I provided? Can you please post your complete javascript code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65509/discussion-between-arincool-and-user3501587).